# Execute java application with one icon

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to replicate the behavior of Linux where we create an application launcher using `Alacarte` providing it the command and file name and Icon using batch

However I have never used batch.

The batch file is in the same directory as the java application.

The Batch contains the command as:

`java -javaagent:app1.jar -jar app2.jar`

Which does the job but It keeps CMD running in the background which during work I always accidentally close it which turns out closing the java app.

How can I can make it so it will disappear after launching the app and keep the app running